# Detail Disclosure Indicator MKMap to Custom View Controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, annotations, mkmapview, mapkit

**EXTRA CODE ADDED**

I am new to xcode. I have managed to create annotations on my map in various different colours. What I would like to do is have each annotation lead to somewhere new with a disclosure button. I have implemented a right arrow disclosure button now what I need to know is how I link that up so that each annotation will lead to a different view controller of my choice. Here is my current code on my MapViewController implementation.

MainMapViewController.m

```
#import "MainMapViewController.h"
#import "LocationAnnotation.h"

@interface MainMapViewController ()


@end

//Totnes Main Centre Coordinates
#define Totnes_LATITUDE 50.433741
#define Totnes_LONGITUDE -3.685797

//The Dartmouth Inn Coordinates
#define DARTMOUTH_INN_LATITUDE 50.430036;
#define DARTMOUTH_INN_LONGITUDE -3.683873;

//Pub Offers Co-Ordinates

#define TheKingBill_LATITUDE 50.431379
#define TheKingBill_LONGITUDE -3.685495

#define TheSevenStars_LATITUDE 50.431045
#define TheSevenStars_LONGITUDE -3.682945

#define TheLordNelson_LATITUDE 50.430931
#define TheLordNelson_LONGITUDE -3.683644

//Span
#define THE_SPAN 0.01f;


@implementation MainMapViewController

@synthesize mainMapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Set Delegate
    mainMapView.delegate = self;

    //Create the region
    MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;

    //Centre
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centre;
    centre.latitude = Totnes_LATITUDE;
    centre.longitude = Totnes_LONGITUDE;

    //Span
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;
    span.longitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;

    myRegion.center = centre;
    myRegion.span = span;


    //Set The Map View
    [mainMapView setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];


    //Annotation

    NSMutableArray * locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    LocationAnnotation * myAnn;

    //The King Bill Annotation
    myAnn = [[LocationAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"The King Bill"
                                          andSubtitle:@"Another Pub In Town"
                                        andCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(TheKingBill_LATITUDE, TheKingBill_LONGITUDE)
                                                andID:1];
    [locations addObject:myAnn];

    //The Seven Stars Annotations
    myAnn = [[LocationAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"The Royal Seven Stars Hotel"
                                          andSubtitle:@"Hotel In Town"
                                        andCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(TheSevenStars_LATITUDE, TheSevenStars_LONGITUDE)
                                                andID:2];
    [locations addObject:myAnn];

    //The Lord Nelson Annotations
    myAnn = [[LocationAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"The Lord Nelson"
                                          andSubtitle:@"Great Pub In Centre of Town"
                                        andCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(TheLordNelson_LATITUDE, TheLordNelson_LONGITUDE)
                                                andID:3];
    [locations addObject:myAnn];

    [self.mainMapView addAnnotations:locations];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate

- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    MKPinAnnotationView *annView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pin"];

    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;


    int annId = ((LocationAnnotation *)annotation).idNumber;
    annView.pinColor = (annId == 1) ? MKPinAnnotationColorPurple
    : (annId == 2) ? MKPinAnnotationColorGreen
    : MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    return annView;


}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, your right button is of type `UIButton`. Because of this fact you can addTarget to it:

```
[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(YourMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

After user tap on `rightButton` `YourMethod` will be launched.
So for every pin you can add different button with different method, in the same way you are setting `AnnotationColor`

```
int annId = ((LocationAnnotation *)annotation).idNumber;
if (annId == 1)
{
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(MethodWhereYouWillFireYouNewViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
else if (annId == 2)
{
    //similar as above
}
```

Comment: Where exactly would I put this in my code and how would i write this if I was going to put it going to push to a view controller called AboutUsViewController?

Comment: That is brilliant but I am really new to this sorry. How do I do the method? action:@selector(MethodWhereYouWillFireYouNewViewController)

Say I want it to open a new view controller called AboutUsViewController. Thanks, R

Comment: Somewhere in your code just write
    `- (void)MethodWhereYouWillFireYouNewViewController
   {
       //here write code to launch new ViewController. You can find     help here, in StackOverflow, remember that it is different when you are using storyboards and different for xib files
   }`

Method MethodWhereYouWillFireYouNewViewController will be fired when user will tap on button.

Comment: But what sort of code would i write to Launch a new ViewController? I am using a storyboard mode and have a mapview on my view controller moving to another view controller.

Comment: I can't write whole code for you, search for `- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender` and read some articles about storyboarding. It is really simple!

Comment: simple for you. I am confused. I think it is because I am very new to this. I am trying to work it out :S Would I put the void statement in my implementation? Thanks for your help

Comment: still been trying to insert it into my code at the top but no luck :S

Comment: So you won't put it into my code above? I have been trying all day to put it into the correct place. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

set rightbutton's  tag to annID.

rightButton.tag = annId;

and then assign Selector to touchup event:
[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(YourMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

In YourMethod, you can use senders tag for navigating to different view

-(void)YourMethod:(UIButton*)sender
{
if(sender.tag==1)

{

//push viewcontroller1

}

else

{

//push viewcontroller

}

return;
}

Comment: Would you be able to be more specific and implement it in the code I have given so I can see where it goes? Thanks, R

Answer (score 0):

Check This:

-(void)clickOnMapAnnotation:(UIButton*)sender

{

int AnnotationClicked =sender.tag;

```
if(AnnotationClicked ==1)
{
    //PushViewcontroller1
}
else
{
      //PushViewcontroller1
}
```

}

- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id ) annotation {

  if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
      return nil;

  MKPinAnnotationView *annView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pin"];

  int annId = ((LocationAnnotation *)annotation).idNumber;
  annView.pinColor = (annId == 1) ? MKPinAnnotationColorPurple
  : (annId == 2) ? MKPinAnnotationColorGreen
  : MKPinAnnotationColorRed;

  //The Detail Disclosure button that I want to lead to a new view controller.

  UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickOnMapAnnotation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  rightButton.tag = annId;

  annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

  annView.canShowCallout = YES;

  return annView;

}

Comment: Would you be able to apply it to my code. I have no idea where to put this. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I have copied your code and addded my code in between your code.  Please copy this.

Comment: AboutUsViewController *About =[[AboutUsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutUsViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:About animated:YES];
    [About release];

Comment: I have changed my code to show you the full code. Would you be able to insert it where it should be in this as your answer as I can't seem to work it out!

Comment: I really need to see it in my code at the top of the page. 've no idea where to put anything. :( Thanks, R

Comment: I have tried and tried with your code but I can't put it into the correct area. Any change you could implement it in full in my code I have above? Thanks